# Need help linking to local HTML file in Dash app

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

Within my Dash app, I am trying to link to a local html file dependent on the search term input by the user. Below is the code I currently have. From everything I have read online it should be working, but when I click the link it just returns the apps main page. Please help!

```
    import pandas as pd
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


from app import app


df = pd.read_csv('syns.txt', sep = '\n', dtype=str)

layout = html.Div([
    html.H3('PubMedIDs:'),
     dcc.Dropdown(
        id='id-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df
    ], multi=True, placeholder='Choose a gene ...'),
    dcc.Link('PubMedIDs', href= '/assets/BRCA2.html')
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output('PubMedIDs', 'children'),
    [Input('id-dropdown', 'value')])
     
def html_up(id_val):
    dcc.Link('PubMedIDs for '+ id_val, href=f"/assets/{id_val}.html")
```

syns.txt is a short list of gene names: i.e. BRCA2, FAD, etc.

*This code is part of a multipage app, so not everything is included in this code chunk*

Comment: You never call `html_up`.  Did you intend to do that somewhere?

Comment: @TimRoberts it shouldn't need to be called. Once an id_val is chosen from the dropdown menu it would start the callback

Comment: The Output declaration is supposed to refer to a component ID.  You don't have a component ID called "PubMedIDs".  Were you trying to change the href for that Link?  I suspect you want `dcc.Link('PubMedIDs',id='id-link'...` and then `Output('id-link',component_property='href')` and then have html_up `return f"/assets/{id_val}.html", but I know little about Dash.